# Classified permutations using itertools or numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-itertools

I have a series of dimensions which can take discrete values.

For instance, say I have 4 dimensions each containing a keyword from a dimension-specific list:

```
color: black, blue, red, green, yellow
size: xs, s, m, l, xl
material: leather, fabric, cotton, wool
gender: male, female
```

I want to iterate and do some stuff through every possible combination of those dimensions' values.

**Is there a way to do this with `itertools` or `numpy` assuming two different cases?**

- If each dimension can have only one keyword
- If each dimension can have one or several keywords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `itertools.product(*iterables)`? Sounds like it's what you're looking for.

The function takes as many iterables as you want and makes a Cartesian product. Here is an example:

```
import itertools

dimension1 = range(3)
dimension2 = ['a']
dimension3 = ['hello', 'world']

for res in itertools.product(dimension1, dimension2, dimension3):
    print(*res)
```

Output:

```
0 a hello
0 a world
1 a hello
1 a world
2 a hello
2 a world
```

Comment: What do you mean by `dimensions` and `number_of_dimensions`?

Comment: @user5061 that was a bad way to say *iterables. I've fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this with itertools or numpy assuming two different cases?

Using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product
gender = ['male', 'female']
color = ['black', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow']
material = ['leather', 'fabric', 'cotton', 'wool']
size = ['xs', 's','m', 'l', 'xl']
for item in product(color, size, material, gender):
    #do something()
```

You can also use a `generator expressions`

```
for item in ((g, c, m, s) for g in gender for c in color for m in material for s in size):
     #do something()
```

**Output**

```
>>> for item in ((g, c, m, s) for g in gender for c in color for m in material for s in size):
...     print(item)
... 
('male', 'black', 'leather', 'xs')
('male', 'black', 'leather', 's')
('male', 'black', 'leather', 'm')
('male', 'black', 'leather', 'l')
('male', 'black', 'leather', 'xl')
('male', 'black', 'fabric', 'xs')
('male', 'black', 'fabric', 's')
('male', 'black', 'fabric', 'm')
('male', 'black', 'fabric', 'l')
('male', 'black', 'fabric', 'xl')
('male', 'black', 'cotton', 'xs')
('male', 'black', 'cotton', 's')
('male', 'black', 'cotton', 'm')
('male', 'black', 'cotton', 'l')
('male', 'black', 'cotton', 'xl')
('male', 'black', 'wool', 'xs')
('male', 'black', 'wool', 's')
('male', 'black', 'wool', 'm')
('male', 'black', 'wool', 'l')
('male', 'black', 'wool', 'xl')
('male', 'blue', 'leather', 'xs')
('male', 'blue', 'leather', 's')
('male', 'blue', 'leather', 'm')
('male', 'blue', 'leather', 'l')
('male', 'blue', 'leather', 'xl')
('male', 'blue', 'fabric', 'xs')
('male', 'blue', 'fabric', 's')
('male', 'blue', 'fabric', 'm')
('male', 'blue', 'fabric', 'l')
('male', 'blue', 'fabric', 'xl')
('male', 'blue', 'cotton', 'xs')
('male', 'blue', 'cotton', 's')
('male', 'blue', 'cotton', 'm')
('male', 'blue', 'cotton', 'l')
('male', 'blue', 'cotton', 'xl')
('male', 'blue', 'wool', 'xs')
('male', 'blue', 'wool', 's')
('male', 'blue', 'wool', 'm')
('male', 'blue', 'wool', 'l')
('male', 'blue', 'wool', 'xl')
('male', 'red', 'leather', 'xs')
('male', 'red', 'leather', 's')
('male', 'red', 'leather', 'm')
('male', 'red', 'leather', 'l')
('male', 'red', 'leather', 'xl')
('male', 'red', 'fabric', 'xs')
('male', 'red', 'fabric', 's')
('male', 'red', 'fabric', 'm')
('male', 'red', 'fabric', 'l')
('male', 'red', 'fabric', 'xl')
('male', 'red', 'cotton', 'xs')
('male', 'red', 'cotton', 's')
('male', 'red', 'cotton', 'm')
('male', 'red', 'cotton', 'l')
('male', 'red', 'cotton', 'xl')
('male', 'red', 'wool', 'xs')
('male', 'red', 'wool', 's')
('male', 'red', 'wool', 'm')
('male', 'red', 'wool', 'l')
...
```

> - If each dimension can have only one keyword
> - If each dimension can have one or several keywords

Both methods will work even if your lists have one element each.

Comment: Thanks - I guess `itertools.product` have chances of being faster than generator expressions (even if I still haven't tried)

Comment: @Jivan `itertools.product` is  over 1.5 times faster than generator expression in my test and is a hell lot easier to write and read.

Comment: @Michael9 ... and this is much appreciated :)